# handle tab key press outside of AjaxControlToolkit HTMLEditor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I have 4 HTMLEditor controls from the AjaxControlToolkit on the same page. I love everything the control does except for how it handles the tab key. I want the user to be able to tab from one HTMLEditor to another instead of insert tabs into the content in the HTMLEditor. If possible I would want to be able to tab between HTMLEditors and other controls, but if the fix will only work between HTMLEditors I can make that work in this instance.

Any idea how to do this?

I have also tried both the SuppressTabInDesignMode and IgnoreTab and neither seems to do anything

EDIT: Here is some code that I am trying and is not working. I have tried a few combinations of the two tags mentioned above, but none of these examples ignores tab key presses. I redownloaded the ajaxcontroltoolkit to make sure it is up to date.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<HTMLEditor:Editor ID="Editor0" runat="server" TabIndex="1" IgnoreTab="false" SuppressTabInDesignMode="true" Height="200" />
<HTMLEditor:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" TabIndex="2" IgnoreTab="false" SuppressTabInDesignMode="false" Height="200" />
<HTMLEditor:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server" TabIndex="3" IgnoreTab="true" SuppressTabInDesignMode="true" Height="200" />
<asp:Button ID="btnTester" runat="server" Text="testing tab" TabIndex="4" />
```

Drop that code into an ASPX page with the following two lines at the top of the page

```
<%@ Register 
    Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register
    Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
    TagPrefix="HTMLEditor" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The parametre you looking for is the **IgnoreTab=true**

```
<HTMLEditor:Editor runat="server" IgnoreTab="true" ...
```

reference: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/htmleditor/htmleditor.aspx

Comment: So this sounds like it would make sense but it is not working for me. I set it to true on two of the controls and false on the other two. When I press tab the spaces are added to the content instead of focus tabbing to the next control. They are in an UpdatePanel, not sure if that impacts things.

Comment: @Justin did you have download the latest version of this ajax controls ?

Comment: I downloaded the package again to make sure it is the latest version, created a very basic test outside of UpdatePanels and other javascript and I'm still not able to tab between controls. I posted sample code of the test environment.